# How to Remote to a VM over an IAP tunnel with PyCharm

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh, pycharm

I have a google VM instance that has no external IP address assigned. I intend to establish SSH connection through PyCharm installed on my local machine (running macOS).

This can be done in terminal through `gcloud` [IAP tunnel](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/using-tcp-forwarding):

```
gcloud compute ssh <instance_name> --tunnel-through-iap
```

The entry added to `~./ssh/config` for the instance is as following:

```
Host compute.<instance_id>
  HostName compute.<instance_id>
  IdentityFile /Users/<user_name>/.ssh/google_compute_engine
  CheckHostIP no
  HostKeyAlias compute.<instance_id>
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  StrictHostKeyChecking yes
  UserKnownHostsFile /Users/<user_name>/.ssh/google_compute_known_hosts
  ProxyCommand /Users/<user_name>/miniconda3/bin/python3 -S /Users/<user_name>/google-cloud-sdk/lib/gcloud.py beta compute start-iap-tunnel <instance_name> %p --listen-on-stdin --project=<project_name> --zone=us-central1-a --verbosity=warning
  ProxyUseFdpass no
  User <user_name>
```

With VS Code's [Remote-SSH plugin](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh-tutorial), this setting can be used directly to establish SSH connection with no problem ([example](https://medium.com/@albert.brand/remote-to-a-vm-over-an-iap-tunnel-with-vscode-f9fb54676153)).

However, I have difficulty setting up the connection via PyCharm. The **SSH Configurations** tab takes:

```
 - Host: compute.<instance_id>
 - User name: compute.<instance_id>
 - Port: 22
 - Authentication type: key pair
 - Private key file: path to ~/.ssh/google_compute_engine
```

and throws an exception for Host not being in the correct format.
If I try the internal IP address of the VM instance as host, the connection times out.

Is there a plugin similar to `Remote-SSH` in VS Code for PyCharm that can work properly with an IAP-tunnel? Or any other way this can be set up without exposing or assigning an External IP to the VM instance?

Comment: I have found this blog, in case you find it useful https://blog.doit-intl.com/remote-development-with-pycharm-and-google-cloud-1a8bdab3433f

Comment: Thanks, @DamPlz, but the SSH through IAP tunnel is different because there is no external IP exposed.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while, but I was just working on the same thing. I used the same config entry in ~./ssh/config, but PyCharm is doing some checks to make sure that top level Host value is valid (even though it isn't being used). I replaced that with something that would pass their validation checks, but I know I'd never actually use (to avoid potential conflicts).

For example, you can update to this:

```
Host mahmoud.local
  HostName compute.<instance_id>
  IdentityFile /Users/<user_name>/.ssh/google_compute_engine
  CheckHostIP no
  HostKeyAlias compute.<instance_id>
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  StrictHostKeyChecking yes
  UserKnownHostsFile /Users/<user_name>/.ssh/google_compute_known_hosts
  ProxyCommand /Users/<user_name>/miniconda3/bin/python3 -S /Users/<user_name>/google-cloud-sdk/lib/gcloud.py beta compute start-iap-tunnel <instance_name> %p --listen-on-stdin --project=<project_name> --zone=us-central1-a --verbosity=warning
  ProxyUseFdpass no
  User <user_name>
```

Then when you configure the SSH connection in PyCharm, you will want to use Host = mahmoud.local

Answer (score 0):

Yes, also got it to work with the ~/.ssh/config host. At first I got a fingerprint error, but I turned off `StrictHostkeyChecking` and that solved it:

```
Host lukas-notebook-gpu
    HostName compute.1234
    IdentityFile /Users/lbatteau/.ssh/google_compute_engine
    CheckHostIP no
    HostKeyAlias compute.1234
    IdentitiesOnly yes
    StrictHostKeyChecking no
    HashKnownHosts no
    UserKnownHostsFile /Users/lbatteau/.ssh/google_compute_known_hosts
    ProxyCommand /Users/lbatteau/.config/gcloud/virtenv/bin/python3 /Users/lbatteau/google-cloud-sdk/lib/gcloud.py compute start-iap-tunnel lukas-notebook-gpu %p --listen-on-stdin --project=myproject --zone=europe-west4-a --verbosity=warning
    ProxyUseFdpass no
```